# Where to place destroying function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Holla.

I have one question about placing **'destroying function'**.

Globals:

```
HWND g_hInvisible = NULL;

HINSTANCE g_hInstance = NULL;
```

*Code for WinMain:*

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevious, LPSTR lpCmdLine,INT nShows)
{
    MSG msg = {0};

    WNDCLASSEXW wcMain = {0};

    wcMain.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wcMain.style            = CS_SAVEBITS;
    wcMain.lpfnWndProc      = MainWindowProc;
    wcMain.hInstance        = g_hInstance;
    wcMain.lpszClassName    = L"MAINCLASS";

    RegisterClassEx(&wcMain);

HWND hMainWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, L"MAINCLASS", L"Main Class Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, g_hInstance, NULL);


    InvisibleWindowInit();

    InvisibleWindowTerminate(); // <<< PLACE HERE ?

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    InvisibleWindowTerminate(); // <<< OR PLACE HERE ?

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

*Code for InvisibleWindowInit:*

```
BOOL InvisibleWindowInit()
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcInvisible = {0};

    wcInvisible.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wcInvisible.style            = CS_SAVEBITS;
    wcInvisible.lpfnWndProc      = InvisibleWindowProc;
    wcInvisible.hInstance        = g_hInstance;
    wcInvisible.lpszClassName    = L"INVISIBLE";

    RegisterClassEx(&wcInvisible);

    g_hInvisible = CreateWindowEx(0, L"INVISIBLE", L"INVISIBLE", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, g_hInstance, NULL);

    if (g_hInvisible == NULL)
    {
        dError = GetLastError();

        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

*Code for InvisibleWindowTerminate:*

```
VOID InvisibleWindowTerminate()
{
    DestroyWindow(hInvisible);

    g_hInvisible = NULL;
}
```

I want to in another piece of code call **InvisibleWindowTerminate**

So where is better place, before message loop or after ?

Thank you.

Comment: Window should be destroyed as reaction to a Windows message then inside message loop. Not before loop (it's useless to create it and immediately to destroy it). Not after loop. Moreover (because it's the only application's window) you don't even need to set global variable to NULL.

Comment: @Adriano: Yes I understand, but I want perform some future tasks in InvisibleWindowTerminate, so I dont send DestroyWindow directly. Also in future, I want main window and invisible window.

Comment: Yes, keep InvisibleWindowTerminate() but call it instead of DestroyWindow() when Windows _asks_ you to quit your application (for example). Inside message loop, not after or before (!) it.

Comment: The question does not make sense. Write up a proper specification for when to destroy the invisible window and the question will vanish. It's not like one or the other option is better or worse. It's rather that at least one of the options is wrong altogether.

Comment: I edit this question, for better understanding. :)

Comment: @Adriano: Your pointing about g_hInvisible is errornous. Maybe in another file is declared as extern. Please avoid useless comments.

Comment: @Xearinox OP provided skeleton for all his source files. About useless comments...don't you think that to imagine another file with extern is **guessing** little bit too much?

Comment: @Adriano: Please show me one official document, where, is defining globals to null as bad practice.